# WPF Binding a Grid's SizeChanged event not working in MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am trying to set a SizeChanged event trigger for a Grid component. However, the SizeChanged event trigger seems not to work at all. When in debug mode, the SizeChanged method(Resize()) is not even called. Below is part of my xaml code.

```
<Border BorderThickness="0.5" BorderBrush="Black" Grid.Row="0">
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <!-- Below is the Grid I want to fire SizeChanged event -->
        <Grid Width="{Binding GridWidth}" Height="{Binding GridHeight}">
            <!-- Some canvas component in the Grid has been delete for simplicity -->                
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SizeChanged">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OnSizeChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

The viewmodel code is as below.

```
    public ICommand OnSizeChanged { get; set; }
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        OnSizeChanged = new RelayCommand(Resize);
    }
    public void Resize()
    {
        // TODO:
    }
```

Could someone explain why this is happening? Thanks a lot.

Comment: One problem is that the command is a two-way binding.  Do you really intend for clients to *set* its value?  Make it a one-way binding.    Remove the `Mode=TwoWay` from the binding.  Remove the setter from the property altogether.  Set the value in the constructor.  It should start to work  Note also that you will probably get this invoked when the window is first shown as its size will change then too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, at first I didn't add the `Mode=TwoWay` binding. But as it didn't work, I tried to add the `Mode=TwoWay` binding to have a try.

Comment: How is the Grid's size supposed to change? You have bound its Width and Height to GridWidth and GridHeight.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I removed the width and height binding and it's working. In my Grid component, there are 3 Canvas components. What I want to do is that when the Grid size changes because of the change of window size or user adjustment, contents in Canvas components can be recalculate to fit. I found maybe properties I should use are `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight`. Thanks again.